# Elements are floating outside of bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form insite a modal. When the size of the window is small then everything is fine. If I maximise the window then the elements of the form are floating outside of the modal. I have checked all my css styling etc, but nothing seems to conflict. I have also set this up on JSFiddle, and it seems to happen and there aswell, with just JQuery and Bootstrap. Its seems to be something on my code but I cant figure out what. Could you please take a look on it and help me out?

http://jsfiddle.net/dsryycbq/

```
<div id="editPassword" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPasswordlbl" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm vertical-align-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="editPasswordlbl">Change Password</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="{{url_for('admin')}}" role="form" id="editPasswordForm" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="formType" value="changePassword">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Repeat Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <!-- Do NOT use name="submit" or id="submit" for the Submit button -->

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have classes set only for smaller devices. `col-sm-3`. What about larger devices? [Check this link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Also see how forms are styled too.

Comment: As a start you need a `form-horizontal` class on the `<form>`

Comment: @anpsmn that's not correct, `col-sm-3` means take up 3 columns on `sm` or larger. The other way around is important, I think it's a good idea to always have a `col-xs-...` class

Comment: Thanks @ckuijjer, You can answer the question, so I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class `.form-horizontal` to the `form` element. This makes the `.form-group`'s act as rows. Next to some margin, this adds a clearfix which stops the columns from "floating".